# How run a custom command from Integrated terminal in VSCode Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created a simple VS Code extension. Now in the Extension's VSCode Integrated terminal, when the user runs a command then corresponding action must be triggered.

How can I achieve this? I have found examples for running from the command palette, but in my case I need it from the Integrated Terminal.

Any leads would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you'll need to write an extension that listens for output in the integrated terminal and then performs the corresponding action when the specified command is detected. You can use the `window.onDidWriteTerminalData` event to listen for terminal output.

Here's a simple example of how you can do this:
In your extension's activation function, set up the event listener:

```
const vscode = require('vscode');
exports.activate = function(context) {
  // Listen for terminal output
  vscode.window.onDidWriteTerminalData(async event => {
    // Check if the output contains the specified command
    if (event.data.includes('your-command')) {
      // Perform the corresponding action
      await yourActionFunction();
    }
  });
};
```

Implement the action function:

```
async function yourActionFunction() {
  // Your code here
  console.log('Action triggered!');
}
```

In this example, when the user runs "your-command" in the integrated terminal, the `yourActionFunction` function will be triggered, which simply logs a message to the console.

Note:-  that you'll need to replace 'your-command' with the actual command you want to listen for, and implement the desired action in the `yourActionFunction` function.

Comment: I am getting the error, "Property 'onDidWriteTerminalData' does not exist on type 'typeof window'".

Comment: please provide a link to the `onDidWriteTerminalData` function in the VSC API doc pages

Comment: if it is proposed API, let it know

Comment: @rioV8 https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/dd076d099840e2fcc4f662cf1d0615f2ed196f4a/src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.terminalDataWriteEvent.d.ts#L29 though note: "`// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78502 This API is still proposed but we don't intent on promoting it to stable due to problems around performance. See #145234 for a more likely API to get stabilized.`"

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?